# How to test whether lines of text are greater than the window height

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to test, please, whether the lines of text in a no-file visiting buffer are greater than the window height -- if not, then

```
(set-window-scroll-bars (get-buffer-window "*Org Agenda*" (selected-frame)) 0 nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test with this:

```
(> (count-lines (point-min)
                (point-max))
   (window-height))
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparing count-lines with window-height works in some cases but doesn't account for line-wrapping, images, and variable-sized fonts.  Another approch is to check if `window-end` is before `point-max`.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative approach, which is ideal for situations where there is at least one character beyond the visible window -- i.e., `(> (point-max) (window-end))` will not return `t` if there are no characters beyond the visible window even if the buffer contains multiple pages of text.

Comment: Right, I assumed that `window-start` is at `point-min`.  If you can't assume it, then you can check it.