# How to automatically add / remove scroll-bars as needed by text height

Tags: emacs, scrollbar, elisp

Many commercial word processors have a default behavior that automatically hides the vertical scroll bars when the lines of text in the document are less than the visible window; and, the scroll bars appear automatically when the lines of text in the document are greater than the visible window.  Emacs is missing that ability and I'd like that to be the default behavior in a variety of different modes.

Does anyone have some ideas how to automatically remove or add the scroll-bars on the fly as the size (lines of text) of the document increases or decreases?

I was thinking of perhaps weaving it into the the functions for line numbers using a prior sample by @phils in a related thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10593165/2112489

I'd like it work even when I'm not using `linum-mode`.  However, I don't think the scroll-bar function should run after every single command -- it should run only when a new line is added or subtracted, taking into consideration `visual-line-mode` (i.e., wrapping being active) potentially being active.

The following snippet was inspired by a previous answer from @abo-abo in a related thread:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/20923695/2112489

```
(cond
  ((not (> (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)) (window-height)))
    (set-window-scroll-bars (get-buffer-window (buffer-name) (selected-frame)) 0 nil))
  ((and
      (> (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)) (window-height))
      (not (equal (window-scroll-bars) `(15 2 t nil))))
    (set-window-scroll-bars (get-buffer-window (buffer-name) (selected-frame)) 15 'right)))
```

---

**EDIT** (January 17, 2014):  Working draft based upon the helpful answer to this thread by @Drew.

**EDIT** (January 19, 2014):  Added a function to count each word-wrapped line using `vertical-motion`.  Setting the `initial-frame-default` seems to be read by Emacs after the initial frame is created, so the scroll bars are visible for a split second -- to avoid seeing this, modifying the frame parameters of the initial frame seems to fix this visual issue.  Now using `window-text-height` instead of `window-height` -- *The returned height does not include dividers, the mode line, any header line, nor any partial-height lines at the bottom of the text area.*  Copied the method used by `linum-mode` in terms of using -- the `post-command-hook`, the `change-major-mode-hook`, and the `window-configuration-change-hook`). Added `window-live-p` condition to avoid `post-command-hook` errors when starting Emacs while various buffers are loading out of sight.  Added condition to deal with `narrow-to-region` -- still unsure why that situation causes Emacs to freeze in a loop or something -- the workaround is needed for now.  The latest version of Emacs Trunk from January 19, 2014 appears to fix visual display issues experienced in prior versions -- as such, `redraw-frame` is no longer necessary.  Added `(redisplay t)` to the function `count-vertical-lines`, which speeds up displaying the new buffer when switching buffers.  Added regexp for buffers that will always have scroll bars or never have scroll bars.

**EDIT** (January 20, 2014):  Added just one main condition that there be a live window, and removed the same conditions from the various branches of the `lawlist-scroll-bar` function.  Added additional condition for a `narrow-to-region` situation such that removing the scroll bars only need occur if scroll bars were present prior to narrowing.

**EDIT** (January 21, 2014):  With this revision, it is no longer necessary to count lines (which causes a slow-down in large buffers).  The new method is a much simpler mathematical calculation based on four (4) points that are determined in a mere fraction of a second -- i.e., `point-min`, `point-max`, `window-start` and `window-end`. If `point-min` moves off the screen, scroll bars are added -- I think this behavior makes sense -- although, I did stop to ponder whether the scroll-bar should also serve as a visual representation of whether the characters within the parameters of `point-min` to `point-max` could actually fit into the window regardless of whether `point-min` had moved beyond the window.  None of the hooks in this example are able to deal with a `display-buffer` situation (targeting the same window of the same frame that both already have focus) -- so, I created my own `display-buffer-hook` (which is beyond the scope of this example).

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; LAWLIST SCROLL BAR MODE ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(defvar regexp-always-scroll-bar '("\\.yes" "\\*Scroll-Bar\\*")
  "Regexp matching buffer names that will always have scroll bars.")

(defvar regexp-never-scroll-bar '("\\.off" "\\.not")
  "Regexp matching buffer names that will never have scroll bars.")

(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(vertical-scroll-bars . nil))

(modify-all-frames-parameters (list (cons 'vertical-scroll-bars nil)))

(defun lawlist-scroll-bar ()
  (when (window-live-p (get-buffer-window (current-buffer)))
    (redisplay t)
    (cond
      ;; not regexp matches | not narrow-to-region
      ((and
          (not (regexp-match-p regexp-always-scroll-bar (buffer-name)))
          (not (regexp-match-p regexp-never-scroll-bar (buffer-name)))
          (equal (- (point-max) (point-min)) (buffer-size)))
        (cond
          ;; Lines of text are less-than or equal-to window height,
          ;; and scroll bars are present (which need to be removed).
          ((and
              (<= (- (point-max) (point-min)) (- (window-end) (window-start)))
              (equal (window-scroll-bars) `(15 2 right nil)))
            (set-window-scroll-bars (selected-window) 0 'right nil))
          ;; Lines of text are greater-than window height, and
          ;; scroll bars are not present and need to be added.
          ((and
              (> (- (point-max) (point-min)) (- (window-end) (window-start)))
              (not (equal (window-scroll-bars) `(15 2 right nil))))
            (set-window-scroll-bars (selected-window) 15 'right nil))))
      ;; Narrow-to-region is active, and scroll bars are present
      ;; (which need to be removed).
      ((and
          (not (equal (- (point-max) (point-min)) (buffer-size)))
          (equal (window-scroll-bars) `(15 2 right nil)))
        (set-window-scroll-bars (selected-window) 0 'right nil))
      ;; not narrow-to-region | regexp always scroll-bars
      ((and
          (equal (- (point-max) (point-min)) (buffer-size))
          (regexp-match-p regexp-always-scroll-bar (buffer-name)))
        (set-window-scroll-bars (selected-window) 15 'right nil))
      ;; not narrow-to-region | regexp never scroll-bars
      ((and
          (equal (- (point-max) (point-min)) (buffer-size))
          (regexp-match-p regexp-never-scroll-bar (buffer-name)))
        (set-window-scroll-bars (selected-window) 0 'right nil)))))

(define-minor-mode lawlist-scroll-bar-mode
  "This is a custom scroll bar mode."
  :lighter " sc"
  (if lawlist-scroll-bar-mode
    (progn
      (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'lawlist-scroll-bar nil t)
      ;; (add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook 'lawlist-scroll-bar nil t)
      ;; (add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'lawlist-scroll-bar nil t)
       )
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'lawlist-scroll-bar t)
    (remove-hook 'change-major-mode-hook 'lawlist-scroll-bar t)
    (remove-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'lawlist-scroll-bar t)))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-lawlist-scroll-bar-mode
  lawlist-scroll-bar-mode lawlist-scroll-bar-on)

(defun lawlist-scroll-bar-on ()
  (unless (minibufferp)
    (lawlist-scroll-bar-mode 1)))

(global-lawlist-scroll-bar-mode)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

---

Supporting regexp function:

```
;; https://github.com/kentaro/auto-save-buffers-enhanced
;; `regexp-match-p` function modified by @sds on stackoverflow
;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343048/distinguishing-files-with-extensions-from-hidden-files-and-no-extensions
(defun regexp-match-p (regexps string)
  (and string
       (catch 'matched
         (let ((inhibit-changing-match-data t)) ; small optimization
           (dolist (regexp regexps)
             (when (string-match regexp string)
               (throw 'matched t)))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to toggle scroll bars on/off interactively, or on a hook, or from your code, then `scroll-bar-mode` should be all you need.

You can also use `menu-bar-no-scroll-bar`, `menu-bar-left-scroll-bar`, and `menu-bar-right-scroll-bar`.  Or just do what each of those commands does: `(customize-set-variable 'scroll-bar-mode WHATEVER)`.  Or use `set-scroll-bar-mode` or `set-window-scroll-bars`, similarly.  It depends on what behavior you are looking for.

I recommend `M-x apropos scroll-bar`.  (Or if you use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles), just `C-h f scroll-bar S-TAB`, then repeat `C-M-down`...)

You can add it to  `mode-line-position`, so that update of the mode line automatically triggers turning scroll bars on/off.  This pretty much works, for instance:

```
(setq-default
 mode-line-position
 '(:eval
   (progn
     (if (> (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)) (window-height))
         (set-window-scroll-bars nil 20 t)
       (set-window-scroll-bars nil 0 t))
     `((-3 ,(propertize
             "%p"
             'local-map mode-line-column-line-number-mode-map
             'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
             'help-echo "Buffer position, mouse-1: Line/col menu"))
       (line-number-mode
        ((column-number-mode
          (10 ,(propertize
                " (%l,%c)"
                'face (and (> (current-column)
                              modelinepos-column-limit)
                           'modelinepos-column-warning)
                'local-map mode-line-column-line-number-mode-map
                'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
                'help-echo "Line and column, mouse-1: Line/col menu"))
          (6 ,(propertize
               " L%l"
               'local-map mode-line-column-line-number-mode-map
               'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
               'help-echo "Line number, mouse-1: Line/col menu"))))
        ((column-number-mode
          (5 ,(propertize
               " C%c"
               'face (and (> (current-column)
                             modelinepos-column-limit)
                          'modelinepos-column-warning)
               'local-map mode-line-column-line-number-mode-map
               'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
               'help-echo "Column number, mouse-1: Line/col menu")))))))))
```

You can alternatively use the following, which employs Stefan's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20925733/729907)
to make it work better with scaled text, `visual-line-mode`, images, etc. However, in that case, scroll bars kick in whenever some text is outside the window because of scrolling, regardless of whether that text would fit in the window.  Whether that is a feature or not is for you to decide. ;-)

```
(setq-default
 mode-line-position
 '(:eval
   (let ((scroll-bars  (nth 2 (window-scroll-bars))))
     (if (or (> (point-max) (window-end))  (< (point-min) (window-start)))
         (unless scroll-bars (set-window-scroll-bars nil 20 t))
       (when scroll-bars (set-window-scroll-bars nil 0 t)))
     (unless (equal scroll-bars (nth 2 (window-scroll-bars))) (redraw-frame))
     `((-3 ,(propertize
             "%p"
             'local-map mode-line-column-line-number-mode-map
             'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
             'help-echo "Buffer position, mouse-1: Line/col menu"))
       (line-number-mode
        ((column-number-mode
          (10 ,(propertize
                " (%l,%c)"
                'face (and (> (current-column)
                              modelinepos-column-limit)
                           'modelinepos-column-warning)
                'local-map mode-line-column-line-number-mode-map
                'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
                'help-echo "Line and column, mouse-1: Line/col menu"))
          (6 ,(propertize
               " L%l"
               'local-map mode-line-column-line-number-mode-map
               'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
               'help-echo "Line number, mouse-1: Line/col menu"))))
        ((column-number-mode
          (5 ,(propertize
               " C%c"
               'face (and (> (current-column)
                             modelinepos-column-limit)
                          'modelinepos-column-warning)
               'local-map mode-line-column-line-number-mode-map
               'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
               'help-echo "Column number, mouse-1: Line/col menu")))))))))
```

Comment: The commercial word processing programs have features where the scroll bar is only visible if the lines of text are greater than the visible window -- that is what I'm looking for.  I'll update the question to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Yes, that is not at all what your question indicate. FWIW, that was discussed (requested) on the Emacs bug list. Specifically, the request was that Emacs do that automatically. The response was that that is impossible, at least on some platforms. But I think your approach is reasonable: just turn off the mode if the window is large enough, and turn it back on if not.

Comment: Thank you for the idea -- I'll look at `line-number-mode` and see where to plug in that snippet.  I'll need to add something that handles `visual-line-mode`, which will probably incorporate the suggestion by `Stefan` in the thread linked in my question -- he made an alternative answer to the one suggested by `abo-abo`.

Comment: I replied above - no room here.

Comment: FYI, I filed a new enhancement request ([#16475](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16475)) for such a feature to be added to Emacs, even though I'm pretty sure this was discussed before. To be implemented properly it should not be done as I did it, but rather in C, and probably not triggered the same way (there is no logical relation to the mode line).

Comment: That is an excellent starting point you gave me -- I have a draft working based on your model -- thank you very much, and thank you for submitting a new enhancement request.

Comment: Glad it helps.  Does the code I posted not work for you completely? It seems to work well for me. What problems do you see?

Comment: It seems to be working fairly well, but the scroll bar doesn't redisplay correctly immediately.  Rather than using the layout of the variable `mode-line-position`, I inserted the snippet in my question into my custom modeline setup function.  However, it triggers every time there is a mode-line update rather than only when line numbers change.  I searched the source code looking for the section where the variable `%l` is used in the hopes of tying in my snippet directly to the line numbering being updated, however, I think that may be buried very deep in the c source somewhere beyond reach.

Comment: I added another condition to prevent my snippet from firing all the time, and I inserted a `(redraw-frame)` when creating scroll-bars.  It has a side-effect of the line-numbers in the left margin temporarily disappearing, but this may be as good as gets for now.  Over the next few days I'll see if I can get the line numbers to reappear any faster.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: See my update above, which adds an alternative that accounts for display artifacts, following Stefan's suggestion. It has the "feature" that it adds a scroll bar even if the text is no larger than the window, if some of the text is outside the window (because it is scrolled).  To me, that is distracting, but you might prefer it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are used to using scroll bars only as visual indicator of where you are in the buffer (rather than looking at the modeline for that), you might like a package like [yascroll](https://github.com/m2ym/yascroll-el).  It uses the fringe for displaying the scroll bar, and it does not show it if lines of text in the document are less than the visible window, as you want.

Advantage is that there is no widgets taking up real state from your screen.

Disadvantage is that you cannot use the scroll bars with the mouse (some users never do that, anyways)

Comment: Thanks -- I'll check it out -- my proposed code in the edit to my question was causing some problems with displaying dired-mode and other things -- so I'll need to keep working on this issue.